# Example of sequence of functions that are differentiable and converge uniformly to |x| on [-1,1]

Tags: sequence-of-function

Is there an example of sequence of functions $f_n$ that are differentiable and converge uniformly to $|x|$ on $[-1,1]$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The inequality $\lvert x \rvert \le \sqrt{x^2 + \frac 1 {n^2} }\le \lvert x \rvert + \frac 1 n$ shows that  $$f_n(x) = \sqrt{x^2 + \frac 1 {n^2}}, \hspace{3mm} x \in [-1,1], \hspace{3mm} n \in \mathbb N $$ works.